# ReactJS buttons or submit functions created by webpack isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

so I'm creating a ReactJS app and configuring webpack for it.
below's my webpack config:

> webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const path = require( 'path' );
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev;
}, {});

module.exports = {
   context: __dirname,
   entry: ['./src/js/index.js','./src/sass/index.scss'],
   output: {
      path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
      filename: 'main.js',
      publicPath: '/',
   },
   devtool: 'eval-source-map',
   devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            query: {
                presets: ['@babel/react', "@babel/preset-env"]
            }
         },
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            query: {
                presets: ['@babel/react', "@babel/preset-env"]
            }
        },
         {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        },
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
         },
         {
            test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|webp)$/i,
            use: [
               'file-loader',
               {
                  loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                  options: {
                  bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
                  disable: true, // webpack@2.x and newer
                  },
               },
            ],
         }
    ]
   },
   plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve( __dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            "React": "react",
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'public/assets' }
            ]
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
   ]
};
```

It was all going well until I realized that all my buttons aren't working, I checked all the functions and the syntax to make sure if I get it wrong, but turns out I am making no mistake about it

here's the function to my button:

```
const submitMail = e => {
    console.log('here')
    alert('here')
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('test')
}
```

I tried to call it in my test button, but it wouldn't work, it sent no alert, it won't even log all my console.logs

```
 <button onClick={e => submitMail(e)}>test</button>
```

I also tried to put them in my form to trigger it at onSubmit along with another button inside just to see if it triggers the "console.log" which is also not working:

```
<form onSubmit={e => submitMail(e)}>
  <input id="banner-text-input-email-input-wrapper-email-input" placeholder="Enter your email here"/>
  <input id="banner-text-input-email-input-wrapper-submit-input" onClick={()=>console.log('hi')} type="button" value="Button Value"/>
</form>
```

NOTE:
I've tried to run the normal react app:

> react-script start

and all the buttons are working!! at this point, I can only think that the reason it's not working is because of my webpack config, here's also my webpack command just in case:

> webpack serve --open --mode=development --config=webpack.config.js
> --hot

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser console before or after you click your button?

Comment: no, not at all, which is also very weird to me

Comment: What version of webpack do you use?

Comment: I used webpack version ^4.44.2

Comment: Can you, please, replace `query` with `options` in your babel configuration and try again?

Comment: I've changed it, it's still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229699/discussion-between-ezhikov-and-justinus-amadia-wijaya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, it turns out, I'm very silly at this thing, I'm very new to webpacks, so I thought I needed to put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

in my public/index.html file

after I deleted that part, it all went well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<button onClick={e => submitMail(e)}>test</button>
```

did you try to use

```
<button onClick={submitMail}>test</button>
```

It will implicitly send the event if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: your webpack seems fine, although im not webpack expert... can you show your function in the context of the component?

Comment: I'll update the question with more things I tried in my component, the whole code is just a huge chunk of HTML div

Answer (score 1):

If we upgrade the Webpack V5, any click event is not working. So we need to delete the  tag in `public/index.html` if you are used.
It should works.